Mockoon filter to get matching ids in an array
I have data in Mockoon, it is static and not faker generated connected to an articles crud endpoint.
Each item has a create_by and I am able to get a list of articles created by a specific id, eg all articles created by use with id of 3
http://localhost:3336/articles?created_by.id_eq=3
However I also have a collaborators key which is an array of multiple collaborators
"collaborators": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Some Name",
    "email": "some@site.co",
    "photo_url": "https://ca.slack-edge.com/T03Q4CLA8-U3P6VEAAE",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Abother Name",
    "email": "name@site.co",
    "photo_url": "https://ca.slack-edge.com/T03Q4CLA8-U3P6VEAAE",
  }
]

I'd like to do similar to above but get all articles where the collaborator id matches 3.
Something like:
http://localhost:3336/articles?collaborators[id]_eq=3
I have tried a few combinations but none work.
Is this possible?

The search feature uses object-path (it's undocumented) which syntax does not allow for this kind of query. You could eventually use something like collaborators.0.id to check the content of the first array element (or the second, etc).
There is no alternative I see yet.
Feel free to open an issue in the repository.
